# How to display technical codec info for a FLAC file?

Tags: command-line, gui, flac

Given a `.flac` file, how is it possible to query and display the technical info relating to the codec? I looked into `man flac` with no luck (the `--analyze` output is not humanly parseable). I'm specifically interested in the **bit rate** (say, 16 bits per sample), the **sample rate** (say, 44.1 KHz) and the **number of channels**.

Either GUI or CLI utilities are acceptable.

Comment: VLC player can show you all this information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flac) page,

```
# -a, --analyze
# Analyze a FLAC encoded file (same as -d except an analysis file is written) 
flac -a myfile.flac
```

**EDIT**

It might be easier to use [soxi](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxi.html) from the [Sound eXchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) project. On most Linux systems you need to install the `sox` package. On Debian derived distributions (including Ubuntu), you would use

```
sudo apt-get install sox
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But the output is completely bonkers to me.

Comment: @landroni Okay. Edited to add [soxi](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxi.html).

Comment: Perfect. `soxi` does what I wanted.

Comment: Try `flac -ac file.flac | grep -E '(sample|channels)'` for a quick 2 out of 3 answers. All those gui tools do is read from that sort of output... Also -a will create an .ana file with the output... -c allows output to stdout.

Answer (score 12):

Easiest is to use the Unix command line utility `file`.  For example:

```
file "example.flac" 
example.flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 16 bit, stereo, 44.1 kHz, 2474304 samples
```

Answer (score 11):

`metaflac --list` will display that information (and more) for all blocks in a FLAC file. You can additionally use `--block-number=X`, where X is the block you want to have information about, to only get information about that particular block.

Comment: `metaflac` is also very useful.

Comment: The commands: metaflac --show-bps,
metaflac --show-channels,
metaflac --show-sample-rate,
will do exactly what the OP poster wanted. Thanks for suggesting metaflac in the first place!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `ffprobe` CLI tool that's included with `ffmpeg`:

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner 10\ Ivory\ Tower.flac
Input #0, flac, from '10 Ivory Tower.flac':
  Metadata:
    ARTIST          : Van Morrison
    TITLE           : Ivory Tower
    ALBUM           : No Guru, No Method, No Teacher
    DATE            : 1986
    track           : 10
    GENRE           : Rock
    disc            : 1
    TOTALDISCS      : 1
    TOTALTRACKS     : 10
  Duration: 00:03:36.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 946 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
```

Shows the duration, bitrate, and particulars about the FLAC encoding. `ffmpeg/ffprobe` use the term streams, so the file we gave it is considered `Stream#0:0`.

You can get just those details:

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner 10\ Ivory\ Tower.flac |& grep Stream
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
```

Or if you really want to get at all the data from the stream use the `-show_streams`:

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner  -show_streams 10\ Ivory\ Tower.flac
Input #0, flac, from '10 Ivory Tower.flac':
  Metadata:
    ARTIST          : Van Morrison
    TITLE           : Ivory Tower
    ALBUM           : No Guru, No Method, No Teacher
    DATE            : 1986
    track           : 10
    GENRE           : Rock
    disc            : 1
    TOTALDISCS      : 1
    TOTALTRACKS     : 10
  Duration: 00:03:36.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 946 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=flac
codec_long_name=FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec)
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=9556764
duration=216.706667
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=16
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
```

See references below for more examples etc.

#### References

- [ffmpeg Documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html)
- [ffprobe Documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html)
- [wiki:FFprobeTips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips)